# Почему неправильно срабатывает проверка условия?

Tags: java

```
final Elements element = new Elements();
if (element.password != element.pass.getText()) ...
```

В классе Elements

```
String password="qwe";
JTextField pass = new JTextField();
```

Условие всегда правильное, else никогда не выполняется.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Уже в который раз подымался этот вопрос, в java вместо !=, == - используется **equals**, т.е. в вашем случае условие должно выглядеть так

```
!element.password.equals(element.pass.getText())

А условие верное т.к. вы сравниваете не значение строк а объекты строк, таким образом, естественно - вы всегда будете получать false и условие всегда будет выполнятся...
```

Answer (score 5):

Дело  в том, что при приложении к ссылкам на объекты (в том число и к String) операторов == или != проверяется, ссылаются ли они на один и тот же объект, т.е. на экземпляр класса. Для сравнения содержимого объектов, на которые ссылаются те или иные переменные, нужно использовать метод equals()

```
if(!element.password.equals ( element.pass.getText())) ....
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, пока на грабли не наступишь, не будешь осторожен... еще раз спасибо

Comment: Не забываем ставить плюсик

Comment: @smail2133, не расстраивайтесь, через эту ошибку прошли практически все )))

Comment: добавлю - кто невнимательно читал книги по java ^.^

Comment: Да нет, надо просто не отрываться от того, что в машине есть **адреса** и представлять во что могут транслироваться объекты.

Comment: Да я книжек не читал, в технаре задание то дали не из простых а знаий то не много, и розбирайся сам как хочь ... Кстате не можете дать свой icq, пускай в контактах полежит.